# How to use byobu without keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: byobu

I'm on a mac, so some of the function keys shortcuts don't work without a bunch of messing around, which I'd rather avoid.  Instead, I'd really like to just execute the command the keyboard shortcut would have executed, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Specifically, I want to create a new session, and the keybindings file says: C-S-F2 new-session.  How do I run new-session from inside an existing byobu session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to open the console is `C-a :`. From there new-session and any other long-form command will work.